# Why Mp3 (sound) is not working when I execute my Python program through Crontab?

Tags: python, audio, cron, raspberry-pi

I have developed a program to execute a python program to be executed in schedule time using crontab, the crontab is executing the program.

I am using `playsound(filename)` in python to execute the file.

I am using the `raspberry pi 4` with

```
 >>> crontab -l

 1 11 * * * python /home/pi/athanpro/MainExcV2.py Dhuhr
```

Comment: Format img in proper way. Include your code.

Comment: You may want to check which user is used to execute the cron job, then check if that user can play sounds at all etc - beside that this question is missing critical details - like what OS, what code is executed, what user is used to execute it by, what is needed to use "playsound(...)" (right-management) etc. You are probably better off, asking in superuser - questions related to cron pop up more often in there then here.

Comment: Maybe related/helpful:   [help-using-crontab-to-play-a-sound (on askubuntu.com)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719590/help-using-crontab-to-play-a-sound)

Answer (score 0):

well, I find the solution, and I would like to share it with you.
in order to add this (XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000) to the top of the file automatically. I used python os as following
import os
os.system('crontab -l | (cat;echo "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000") | crontab')